# LaravelのSocialiteを用いたGoogle認証でグーグルアカウントを選択しログインしたとき正常にリダイレクトされない

Tags: laravel, google-api

認証までは問題なさそうなのですが、認証後のリダイレクト先で「このサイトにアクセスできません」と出てしまいます。
とくにエラー表示は出ていないです。ご教授お願いします。
環境：DockerToolbox使用。
Windows10

GoogleAPIでのリダイレクトURL
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
アドレス欄に設定されたURLが書いてある。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
web.php

```
Route::prefix('login')->name('login.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{provider}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')->name('{provider}');
    Route::get('/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback')->name('{provider}.callback');
});
```

ルーティングを指定しています。

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//===========ファサード==========
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    // 略
    public function redirectToProvider(string $provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, string $provider)
    {
        $providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

        $user = User::where('email', $providerUser->getEmail())->first();

        if ($user) {
            $this->guard()->login($user, true);
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
        
    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
<h2 class="h3 card-title text-center mt-2">ログイン</h2>

   <a href="{{ route('login.{provider}', ['provider' => 'google']) }}" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
       <i class="fab fa-google mr-1"></i>Googleでログイン
   </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
DokcerToolboxを使用している場合、ポートフォワーディングという処理をしないといけないようです。

管理者権限でコマンドプロントを開き以下のコマンドを実行すると、正常にリダイレクトされるようになりました。

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.99.100
netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4
```

ありがとうございました。